# Generate sequence between each element of 2 vectors

Tags: r

I have a for loop that generate each time 2 vectors of the same length (length can vary for each iteration) such as:

```
>aa  
[1] 3 5  

>bb  
[1] 4 8
```

I want to create a sequence using each element of these vectors to obtain that:

```
>zz  
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Is there a function in R to create that?

Comment: What do you expect from `aa<-1:2` and `bb<-4:5`? `c(1,2,4,5)` or `1:5`?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Map`to get the sequence of corresponding elements of 'aa' , 'bb'.  The output is a `list`, so we `unlist` to get a `vector`.

```
unlist(Map(`:`, aa, bb))
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

#### data

```
aa <- c(3,5)
bb <- c(4, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can obtain a sequence by using the colon operator `:` that separates the beginning of a sequence from its end. We can define such sequences for each vector, `aa` and `bb`, and concatenate the results with `c()` into a single series of numbers.

To avoid double entries in overlapping ranges we can use the `unique()` function:

```
zz <- unique(c(aa[1]:aa[length(aa)],bb[1]:bb[length(bb)]))
#> zz
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

with

```
aa <- c(3,5)
bb <- c(4,8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your desired output, here are a few more alternatives:

```
> do.call("seq",as.list(range(aa,bb)))
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8

> Reduce(seq,range(aa,bb)) #all credit due to @BrodieG
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8

> min(aa,bb):max(aa,bb)
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
```